# Create an array for key value in hash (Perl)

Tags: perl, hash

I am having a very small difficulty in Perl.

I am reading a text file which for some information. While I read the text file, I select some keys from text; as I read further, I wish to save an array of values for the keys.

See for e.g.

```
Alpha 1

Something: 2132
Something: 2134

Alpha 2

Something: 2132
Something: 2134
```

I read the file into an array called lines:

```
my $h;
my $alpha;
for my $line (@lines){
    if ($line =~ m/Alpha (\d+)/){
        $alpha = $1;
        $h->{$alpha} = (); # create empty array for key?
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/Something: (\d+)/){
        push($h->{$alpha}, $1);
    }
}
```

Apparently, it gives me an error:

```
Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not hash element) at test.pl line 28, near "$1)"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hash key value can contain only a scalar. If you want to store an array, then you need to go for array reference.

You can do something like this:

```
for my $line (@lines){
    if ($line =~ m/Alpha (\d+)/){
        $alpha = $1;
        $h->{$alpha} = []; # create empty array refernece for key
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/Something: (\d+)/){
        push( @{$h->{$alpha}}, $1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great. I've understood it now. Thanks.

Comment: Testcase: `$alpha` may remain `undef`. Shouldn't that be taken care of?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make two changes:

```
    $h->{$alpha} = [];
                   ** - Create an anonymous array and store 
                        a ref to it in the hash
```

And

```
    push(@{$h->{$alpha}}, $1);
```

because `push` requires an actual array, and you have an array reference. The @{...} wrapper dereferences the arrayref to an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

As earlier answers say, they are correct. But not perfect. `$alpha` may remain `undef`. Hence in order to avoid it please add a `check`.

```
my $alpha;
for my $line (@lines){
    if ($line =~ m/Alpha (\d+)/){
        $alpha = $1;
        $h->{$alpha} = []; # create empty array refernece for key
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/Something: (\d+)/){
        if(defined $apha) { ## Check
           push( @{$h->{$alpha}}, $1);
        }
    }
}
```